# Geotools coverage warp

Tags: java, geotools, jpg

I have some small JPEG images that I wish to load as an image mosaic. I have programmatically created JGW files for each JPEG, and the files display correctly in QGIS.

[image: source image with skew]

However, the affine transform used in the JGW includes skew and rotation, so the files will not load correctly with an ImageMosaicReader. The input images need to be deskewed before I can load them into an image mosaic (the images are already in the correct projection, so do not need to be reprojected).

I used QGIS to apply a warp/reproject to the image, to get a deskewed version of it, but I cannot work out how to get the same result programmatically using Geotools.

[image: result from QGIS Warp (reproject) process]

I thought I would easily be able to apply a warp to each JPEG coverage, resave, and then use these 'rectified' coverages as the image mosaic granules, but nothing I have tried works - I either end up with an output identical to my input, or a black image in the correct location.

This is my code:

```
WorldImageFormat worldImageFormat = new WorldImageFormat();

// load the input jpg
GridCoverage2DReader jpgReader = worldImageFormat.getReader(new File("c:/temp/input.jpg"));
GridCoverage2D input = jpgReader.read(null);

// read the affine transform from the jgw
WorldFileReader worldFileReader = new WorldFileReader(new File("c:/temp/input.jgw"));
GridCoverage2D output = (GridCoverage2D)Operations.DEFAULT.warp(input, new WarpAffine(worldFileReader.getAffineTransform()));

// save the output to png
GridCoverageWriter pngWriter = worldImageFormat.getWriter(new File("c:/temp/output.png"));
pngWriter.write(output, null); // creates a black image, in the correct location
```

As well as the warp operation, I have also tried crop (using the input coverage's own envelope) and resample, but nothing works. I either get an output image the same as the input, or a black square.

How do I apply the equivalent operation in Geotools to the QGIS coverage warp(reproject) process?

I am using Java (OpenJDK) 8, with Geotools 28.5, as that appears to be the last version that supports Java 8.